# Re-populate upload file field in codeigniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I want to re-populate upload field in form in codeigniter here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php if(isset($upload_error) && !empty($upload_error)): ?>
        <p><?php echo $upload_error ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php echo validation_errors() ?>

        <?php echo form_open_multipart('')  ?>

        Enter title:  <br>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo set_value('title') ?>" > <br><br>    

        Enter Content:<br>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="content"><?php echo set_value('content') ?></textarea> <br><br>

        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('userfile') ?>"> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried `set_value` in `userfile` but it didn't work. Pls tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot due to security reasons. The browser shouldn't have access to the user file system without premission.

Comment: First of all, different OSs have different paths... but imagine if your website could have accessed the files on my computer :) You would have been able to do foreach and scan my entire harddisk...